# Python code between django "autoescape off" marks can not be executed

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to establish a blog using Django. I directly stored HTML into models. And I used `{% autoescape off %}` and `{% endautoescape %}` marks in HTML files that tells Python do not autoescape HTML code to string. Between the marks, I used codes like `{{ article.content }}` to load HTML codes stored in models.

The problem is that `<img src="{% static 'img/dot.png' %}">` (HTML codes stored in models) will be displayed as `{%%20static%20'img/dot.png'%20%}`. The python codes won't be executed.

I feel helplessness. Does anyone have a good idea?

Here is a example of one template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% load static %}
        <div style='margin:0 auto;width:0px;height:0px;overflow:hidden;'>
            <img src="{% static 'img/wechat.png' %}">
        </div>
        <header>
            <div id="logo">
                <span class="heading_desktop">You are browsing&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="/index" class="logotype">Paradox</a><span class="heading_tablet">&nbsp;&nbsp;, a personal site</span><span>&nbsp;of&nbsp;</span><a href="/me">Jiawei Lu</a><span class="heading_tablet">&nbsp;since 2015</span><span class="phone_h">.&nbsp;Happy<script>document.write(" " + whatDay());</script>.</span>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/index" class="selected">Articles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/me">Jiawei Lu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <hr class="red">
        </header>

        <div id="breadcrumb" class="article">
            <a href="/index">Articles</a> &rarr; {{ article.title }}
        </div>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <article>
                <h1 class="article">{{ article.title }}</h1>
                <div id="post_info">
                    <p>Published on {{ article.timestamp }}<!--<span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>--></p>
                    <!-- Category inside article <p><a href="#">Category 1</a><a href="#">Category 2</a><span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span></p> -->
                    <!-- Share inside article <p>Share: Email/Linkedin</p> -->
                </div>
                <div id="post_content" class="article">
                    {% autoescape off %}
                    {{ article.content }}
                    {% endautoescape %}
                </div>
            </article>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

article.content: HTML Codes, like

```
<h1>Test</h1> 
<img src="{% static 'img/dot.png' %}">
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "HTML codes stored in models". Are you trying to render template code from a model field? Please show your actual template.

Comment: Template added. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have anything to do with autoescaping. When Django outputs a variable, it doesn't do anything to interpret whatever is in that variable; so putting template tags into a model field won't work.

You would need to do something to render that data yourself manually; perhaps a custom template tag, or a model method, that uses the [Template API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#loading-a-template) to instantiate a template object and call its `render` method.